# Kashering frozen meat

Tags: halacha, kashering-kosherization, blood, salt

Because of the prohibition against eating blood ([Vayikra 7:26](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9908#v=26), ועוד), the blood that is in meat has to be removed, before it can be eaten. This is usually accomplished by salting the meat, though there are other methods.

What happens if the meat is frozen? Would that impact the ability of the salt to draw out the blood?
Assuming frozen meat cannot be salted, what about meat that had been frozen, and was subsequently defrosted?

Comment: See Rema to [YD 68](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4139):11 and באר היטב [YD 69](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4143):8.

Comment: There is an Aruch Hashulchan and Igros Moshe on this

Comment: Frozen meat that had not been salted was imported to Israel under Rabbanut hechsher, but in recent years the meat has been salted before import (presumably before freezing).

Comment: @Epicentre I believe in those cases the meat was salted after being defrosted. The question there was does freezing pause the 72 hours where one can salt meat (accd to the Geonim).

Answer (score 7):

[Rabbi Kaganoff quotes the following authorities and their rulings.](http://rabbikaganoff.com/the-crisis-of-unwashed-meat/)

Minchas Yaakov Responsum #14 at end quoted in Be'er Hataiv 69:8, Pri Megadim Sifsei Daas 69:60 both say that frozen meat may only be broiled.

Aruch Hashulchan Yore Deah 69:79, Yad Yehuda 69:59, Yabia Omer 2 Yore Deah 4, Yechave Da'as 6:46 say that deep freezing prevents blood from hardening, so the meat can be salted even after three days.

Igros Moshe Yore Deah 1:27 & 2:21 say it is best not to Kasher by salting L'chatchila however would permit doing so in extenuating circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן לו - הלכות מליחה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0035_L2)  writes:

> **סעיף ה':**  בָּשָׂר שֶׁנִּקְרַשׁ מֵחֲמַת הַקֹּר, צְרִיכִין לְהַשְׁגִּיחַ שֶׁיִּפָֹּשֵר, אֲבָל לֹא יַנִּיחוּהוּ אֵצֶל תַּנוּר שֶׁהֻסָּק. ובִשְׁעַת הַדְּחָק יְכוֹלִין לִשְׁרוֹתוֹ בְּמַיִם פּוֹשְׁרִין (סח סט ובחכמ"א). ‏

One must make sure that meat that froze because of the icy weather (this was written before freezers were invented) is fully defrosted [before salting].

However, one should not put it close to a burning furnace.

In emergency [when there's no time to wait for it to defrost by itself, like on Erev Shabbat], one can soak it in warm water.

How warm?

The Remo & Be'er Heitev in שלחן ערוך - יורה דעה in [סימן סח - דיני מליגת הראש והעופות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_7.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2) says that if possible it should be below *Yad Soledes Bo* [so hot you cannot keep your hand in it], but in emergency [like visitors need to be fed] then one could use boiling water.

> **יא:** אֲפִלּוּ בִּכְלִי שֵׁנִי, יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁלֹּא יִמְלֹג; וְאִם מָלַג, מֻתָּר. **הגה**: דְּקַיְמָא לָן כְּלִי שֵׁנִי אֵינוֹ מְבַשֵּׁל, אֲפִלּוּ הַיָּד סוֹלֶדֶת בּוֹ (מָרְדְּכַי פֶּרֶק הַשּׁוֹכֵר) וּבְדִיעֲבַד שָׁרֵי, אֲבָל (יט) לְכַתְּחִלָּה אָסוּר (הַגָּהוֹת ש''ד שַׁעַר י''ד) וְלָכֵן נָהֲגוּ בְּאֵלּוּ הַמְּדִינוֹת שֶׁלֹּא לִמְלֹג שׁוּם דָּבָר רַק אַחַר מְלִיחָה. **מִיהוּ לִכְבוֹד אוֹרְחִים אוֹ צֹרֶךְ שַׁבָּת**, (כ) **מֻתָּר לְהַנִּיחַ בִּכְלִי שֵׁנִי, אֲפִלּוּ לְכַתְּחִלָּה, חֲתִיכָה מְלֵאָה קֶרַח וּכְפוֹר כְּדֵי לְמַהֵר מְלִיחָתוֹ. וְטוֹב** (כא) **לִזָּהֵר לְכַתְּחִלָּה שֶׁלֹּא לְהַנִּיחוֹ רַק בְּמַיִם שֶׁאֵין הַיָּד סוֹלֶדֶת בָּהֶם. וְאֵין חִלּוּק בֵּין כְּלִי חֶרֶס אוֹ כְּלִי** (כב) **נְחֹשֶׁת אוֹ שְׁאָר כֵּלִים, לְעִנְיַן כְּלִי שֵׁנִי**. (כֵּן מַשְׁמָע לוֹ מִדִּבְרֵי הַפּוֹסְקִים) .‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (**יט**) **לכתחלה**. פי' אם היד סולדת בו (אבל אם אין יד סולדת בו אף בכלי ראשון שרי): (**כ**) **מותר**. אפי' היד סולדת בו: (**כא**) **ליזהר**. אם אפשר ליזהר: (**כב**) **נחשת**. כתב הש''ך בשם ר' ירוחם ושאר פוסקים דאם עירה יורה בשר לתוך כלי נחשת של חלב א''צ הגעלה דכלי נחושת אינו בולע אא''כ האור מהלך תחתיו והוא השיג ע''ז והוכיח מש''ס ופוסקים דאף כלי נחשת צריך הגעלה והסכים עמו הגאון מוהר''ר יושע: ‏